# How to set table to LOGGED in postgresql 9.2?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.  I created a bunch of UNLOGGED tables, loaded data into there, and created primary keys.  Now I'd like to set them back to LOGGED status.

I tried the command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET LOGGED;
```

However, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOGGED"
```

What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: You cannot. That capability didn't get added until 9.5. In 9.2, you'll have to create and populate a new, logged, table from the old one.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 [is no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) anyway. So you should upgrade to a current version as soon as possible (which then will also allow you to change the table to LOGGED).